# Sha512 not returning equal in c# hash validation

Tags: c#

The 64 bytes are the same, but the == is returning false.  I am guessing there may be something wrong with the encoding, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any ideas to fix this?

```
public static byte[] hashSHA512(string unhashedValue)
{
    SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] hash = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unhashedValue));
    return hash;

}

public static bool Validate(string enteredValue, byte[] hashedValue)
{
    byte[] hash = hashSHA512 (enteredValue);
    return (hash == hashedValue);
}
```

I tested this with a simple value and since they both call the same hash method I do not see how it can fail other than something in the encoding.  I am just using the built in System.Security.Cryptography.

Comment: Use `hash.SequenceEqual(hashedValue)` to compare the two arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with the encoding - there *is* no encoding in a `byte[]`. They're just bytes. It's just a matter of `==` for arrays performing a reference comparison.

You could use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567) to compare the arrays:

```
public static bool Validate(string enteredValue, byte[] hashedValue)
{
    // TODO: Rename `hashSHA512 to follow .NET naming conventions
    byte[] hash = hashSHA512 (enteredValue);
    return hash.SequenceEqual(hashedValue);
}
```

Note that you'll need `using System.Linq;` in your using directives to bring in LINQ.

Alternatives:

- Convert both to their base64 (text) representations and compare those
- Write your own array equality checker, which could easily be more efficient than `SequenceEqual`

Comment: Ok stupid moment for me.  I actually thought about that but thought I was clear with == and did not even look into that.  I guess I learned two things today, because I am using Xamarin and did not think LINQ was working in mono, but that fix works just fine even on a MAC.  Thanks for the super fast help.

Comment: Yeah when you pointed out the reference equals I thought about creating an equality checker, but since I just needed a quick simple proof of concept skeleton the SequenceEqual was plenty fast.

Answer (score 6):

In C#, two arrays are only equal to another if they are identical, i.e. they are the *exact same* array. The normal equality comparison will not check whether the contents of those arrays are equal:

```
byte[] x = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] y = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(x == y); // false
```

You can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to check whether the *contents* are equal:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.SequenceEqual(y)); // true
```

Since SHA512 hash sums are often displayed in hexadecimal, it might make sense for you to actually return a hexadecimal string instead of a byte array. You can use one of the [many ways to convert a byte array into a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa). And then, you can just perform an equality check on the string—which will work as you expect.